# Undfined variable 'posts' - Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

In my ShowController, I returned a view with variable posts, like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Depress;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ShowController extends Controller
{
    public function showPost(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = Depress::all();
        return view('homeview')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

And in my, homeview.blade.php ,

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">{{ $post->name }}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ $post->depression }}
            </div>
        </div>
 @endforeach
```

But, it's showing,
 Undefined Variable: posts

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

The posts variable is in session. So use **Session::get('posts')** to get it.

Or use **return view('homeview', compact('posts'));** and $posts will be available in view as php variable.

Comment: hey, actually, i m some problem, with my alert, i am making through Session::has('info'), way, but it doesn't seem to appear?

Answer (score 0):

add `use App\Post;` to your ShowController